# Embed a referenced table as a Map of 2 of its attributes in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I start from a database such as:

MainEntity:

```
id | field
--------
1  | 666 
2  | 667
```

Localization:

```
id | lang | text
----------------
666     A      -
666     B      -
666     C      -
666     D      -
667     A      -
667     B      -
667     C      -
667     D      -
```

I'm trying to define field so it embeds the localization reference in a map of lang/texts. Something like:

```
//@Id
@Column(name = "field")
private String field;

@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="lang")
@Column(name="text")
@CollectionTable(name="localization", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumn="field", insertable = false, updateable = false))
private Map<String,String> mappings;
```

But it's not working, any help?

Comment: `But it's not working` is not enough information

Comment: I think the problem is that the join column refers to the primary key of MainEntity, not to the particular field, but not sure how to change it